# Using WIF with asp.net MVC 3, where do I define the STS Sign out endpoint?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, wif, ws-federation

I see that the FedMetadata document can provide signout notification and subscription endpoints, and web.config defines the issuer url for sign in requests, but I can't find where WIF knows to send sign out requests. If the STS I'm using defines different endpoints for sign in and sign out requests, how could I access that in code or set that up in web.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, WIF will redirect to the same STS endpoint for sign-out as was used for sign-in.  To direct to a different endpoint, you'll need to override the sign-out action using `FederatedSignOut`:

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule authModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

string signoutEndpoint = "http://STS/yourendpoint/";  // This can be stored in your configuration app settings
string signoutUrl = WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetFederationPassiveSignOutUrl(signoutEndpoint, authModule.Realm, null);

WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(new Uri(signoutUrl), new Uri(currentPage));
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: This is what I needed to know. I had put the endpoint in the config, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a WIF parameter that took the url in instead.